# Components do not render through <router-view /> in Laravel 5.8 with Vuejs

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to create an SPA using Vuejs and Laravel. I've installed vue-router to accomplish that. The component that has to be rendered inside the

```
<router-view />
```

tag is not rendering.

I've tried creating a new project and installing npm and vue-router again. 
It still does not work.

Laravel Version : 5.8.18
vue-router : 3.0.6

## welcome.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Laravel</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id = "app">
            <router-view></router-view>
        </div>

        <script src = "js/app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

## app.js(./resources/js/app.js)

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import routes from './routes'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

 const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router: new VueRouter(routes)
 });
```

## routes.js(./resources/js/routes.js)

```
import Home from './components/Home'

export default {
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [
    {
        path: '/',
        component: Home
    }
   ]
 }
```

## Home.vue(./resources.components/Home.vue)

```
<template>
    <p>Home</p>
</template>

<script>
    export default {}
</script>
```

## web.php

```
<?php

Route::get('/{any?}', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

Comment: Can you confirm that welcome.php.blade is loading with all the other resources?

Comment: Yes. All of the other resources load correctly. In fact, even if I add a component directly to the page like <Navbar />, it works just fine. The problem is with the vue router

Comment: facing similar problem

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me. Remember to use

```
npm run watch
```

Comment: I did that. There are no errors. The console has nothing too. I don't know where the problem lies.

Comment: Can you copy the contents of your package.json file and comment it here?

Comment: ´{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        ...
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.18",
        "bootstrap": "^4.1.0",
        "cross-env": "^5.1",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^4.0.7",
        "lodash": "^4.17.5",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
        "sass": "^1.15.2",
        "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
        "vue": "^2.5.17",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "vue-router": "^3.0.6"
    }
}

Comment: My app has the same version of all the dependencies. I have no idea what's going wrong.